# matlab2tikz: Generated file is several MB due to resolution

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab, matlab2tikz

I am exporting a surface-plot in Matlab to tikz using `matlab2tikz`, a mwe of the figure is here:

```
stp = 0.001;
[xx yy] = meshgrid(0:stp:1, 0:stp:1);
surf(xx, yy, zeros(size(xx)), sin(xx), 'EdgeColor', 'none')
```

The step-size `stp` is quite low because I need a high resolution, but when I generate a tex-file using `matlab2tikz('output.tex')`, the file is several MB.

Is there a way to get a much smaller file that can be compiled without problems, without increasing the step-size too much in Matlab? Perhaps export the figure itself as png or similar?

Comment: export matlab picture as pdf file and then include it directly with `\includegraphics[width=...]{my-huge-matlab-picture}`?

Comment: @Zarko Thanks, do you mean I should include it in tikz directly? Would like to see a mwe if you know/have one

Comment: no in TikZ, directly in in your document (I assume that it should appear as figure in it). Do you have special reason to import it into TikZ picture? if this is a case, than do this in separate `standalone` document and then result include in document as I suggest in the my first comment.

Comment: @Zarko Just to make it nice and in Latex-style, that is the only reason

Comment: save it as an image in matlab. That's pretty normal